# Manually doing soft-float add

Tags: c, floating-point, floating-point-precision

I need to write a program in C that takes 2 floating point numbers and produces their sum as the output only using int, pointers and malloc(). No other data type. (Single precision)
And I'm helpless.

Comment: You are not allowed to use any `float` *variables*, but how about temporarily casting pointers to `float`?

Comment: If there is no precision requirement, you could read each "side" of the point as a separate int, add the right sides together and add any overflow to the left side when you add those.

Comment: So really no data types allowed at all?!?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) on how to ask a question. What have you tried so far? Nobody here is going to hold your hand and write all your code for you.

Comment: @Deduplicator I don't need any code. I just need some guidance on how to go about it.

Answer (score 2):

**Tip:** A floating point number `x` is really just two integers: a **mantissa** `m` and an **exponent** `e` such that `x = m * 2^e`. That should get you started.

Good read: [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de)

**Edit:** I understood the question as an exercise to understand floating point numbers. Maybe I'm wrong…